# Could the "makes no sense as an edit" option be reworded to not bite the newbies?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, wording, rejection-reasons

I just rejected [a proposed edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13056432) from a low-rep SO user that added code where there was none.  The proposed edit makes total sense as an answer, but the proposer didn't know that.  However, I was not comfortable using the predefined reason:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit.

The phrase "makes no sense" tells the proposer that he doesn't know what makes sense or doesn't make sense.  Having once been a newbie on the receiving end of criticism, I can attest that it is demoralizing to hear that your efforts to make the world a better place are misguided or ignorant.

I know this text came from a [reasoned discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239950/274096) and has been [further commented on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263938/274096) before.  Could we change this message to something more like the below?

- for answers (assuming edits that hack off pieces of the questions can be rejected for other reasons):

  > This edit appears to greatly expand or change the answer.  Please add your proposed edit as a new answer instead, so that each person's answer will get the credit it deserves.

  - And, for bonus credit, it would be great if the "rejected-edit" notification included a link that would automatically copy the rejected edit, and a link back to the original answer, into a new draft answer ready for editing! :)
- for questions: I like [Gilles's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/149076/gilles) proposed [text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238340/274096):

  > To request some clarification or improvement from the author of the question, leave a comment under the question. If you want to provide a solution, use the answer box at the bottom of the page.

**Note**: Josh Caswell rightly points out that the rejection reasons are directed to the person rejecting, not to the suggester of the edit.  However, when I was new on SO, I actually did read the rejection-reason messages in hopes of learning why my edits were rejected! I would be perfectly happy with separate messages to the suggester if that worked better ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11063239) showing the messages being presented to the suggester ;) ).

Comment: I don't like this default reason either, it sounds harsh and unclear. And neither the [edit guidance on the sidebar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rk3qI.png), nor the edit link itself (which says "revise and improve the post") clarify the things there.

Comment: The listed reasons are just that -- _reasons_ to reject -- not messages to the would-be-editor. Note that the dialog box says "Why are **you rejecting** this edit?" (emphasis mine) The answer by Gilles that you linked to also points this out. If you want separate messages for the suggester, that's one thing, but this is not just "making it nicer", it's entirely changing the purpose of this text.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Fair point.  However, when I was new on SO, I actually did read those messages in hopes of learning why my edits were rejected!  I would be perfectly happy with separate messages to the suggester if that worked better.  ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11063239) showing the messages being presented to the suggester ;) )

Comment: I know folks get all tetchy about it, but I'm not wild about adding another excuse for folks to reject answer edits.